# Cannot use relative paths with wp-scripts plugin on npm run build

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

I am using the [@wordpress/scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts) to build out my WordPress plugins using react.  I have edited my apps package.json so that I can dev out the plugin using `react-scripts` using `npm start` whilst usign `wp-scripts` to build out my JS for embedding into the WP Plugin.

**package.json**

```
// ....

"scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build --output-path=build/cwz",
    "format": "wp-scripts format",
    "lint:css": "wp-scripts lint-style",
    "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js",
    "start": "react-scripts start",  <-- So I can dev in real time on the SRC
    "packages-update": "wp-scripts packages-update"
},

// .....
```

My **jsconfig.json** is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "allowJs": true
}
```

Now if I use

```
import 'App.css';
```

I can `npm start` and the app will serve on localhost running as expected.  But if I do a `npm run build` I get the error that `App.css` cannot be found.  Is there a way to force wp-scripts to listen to my `jsconfig.json`?  Putting absolute paths in the imports I can do, but I'd rather not.  It will start looking funky when I am using nested components and have to call

```
import Foo from '../../../../components/foo/bar.js';
```

Where I'd just like to be able to

```
import Foo from 'components/foo/bar.js';
```

Which again .. Works on `npm start`  .. But not `npm run build` using `wp-scripts`.

Without changing the node module code itself, is there a way to force it to listen to my `baseUrl` and my `include` specified in `jsconfig.json`?